# excel web query properties from drop-down online

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am trying to retrieve data from http://www.professorpaddle.com/rivers/riverlist.asp which automatically defaults to Washington state as the state id. However, I want to pull data from the table for Oregon. Can this be done as a property? So far I've tried writing a .iqy file with the following and it still doesn't work:

```
WEB
1
http://www.professorpaddle.com/rivers/riverlist.asp?hstateid=["oregon"]

Selection=EntirePage
Formatting=All
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
```

I am new to VBA but open to using it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two issues:

The page you linked uses a `POST` not a `GET` request so you have to write the parameters separately, not as part of the URL.

I'm not sure why you're supplying `oregon` as the `hstateid`.  When examining the request in Chrome's dev tools I see `37` as the value of this parameter.

And the brackets around the value indicate that you want you to specify variable values for the parameter but I think you're trying to just have a static value here.

So your query should start with something like:

```
WEB
1
http://www.professorpaddle.com/rivers/riverlist.asp
hstateid=37
```